# Angular Component Styles in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a parent component HTML&CSS files for a list of items.

HTML:

```
<div class="notifications-popup popup" *ngIf="showingNotifications" [style.top]="notificationCoords.top + 'px'" [style.left]="notificationCoords.left + 'px'">
  <ul class="notification-list">
    <app-dropdown-notification *ngFor="let data of notifications" [Notifications]="data"></app-dropdown-notification>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import '../../../assets/styles/utils.scss';
@import '../../../assets/styles/layouts.scss';

app-dropdown-notification{
  border-bottom: 1px solid $colorLightGray;
}

app-dropdown-notification:last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

And a child component that builds the items:

```
<span class="container">
<div *ngIf="Notifications.type.video" class= "video component">
    <app-profile-icon class="sent_from" [src]="Notifications.image" size="45px" [color]="Notifications.color"></app-profile-icon>
    <div class= "video">
        <div class="profileName">{{Notifications.name}}</div>
        <div class= "text">{{Notifications.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="Notifications.type.post" class= "post component">
    <app-profile-icon class="sent_from" [src]="Notifications.image" size="45px" [color]="Notifications.color"></app-profile-icon>
    <div class= "video">
        <div class="profileName">{{Notifications.name}}</div>
        <div class= "text">{{Notifications.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</span>
```

CSS of child component is not receiving styles being set within the parent component, despite this method working between other components. TS files are set up the same on both components. Any ideas why the styles are not getting through?

Comment: Maybe view encapsulation is shadowed in this particular component https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `encapsulation` in the parent component  like the following :

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 ...
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**ViewEncapsulation Types**

**1-Emulated (Default)** *[value is 0]*: No shadow DOM but provide style encapsulation by adding new host element attribute to all selectors.

**2-None** *[value is 1]*: No shadow DOM.

**3-ShadowDom** *[value is 2]*:     Uses Shadow DOM for style encapsulation.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! @AbolfazIR

Another thing I tried that may work for some is adding the CSS element selector in the parent:
`app-dropdown-notification{
  .component{
//Add styles here
  }
}`